# IIS7 - why is a deleted site is still accessible?

Tags: iis, iis-7

I deleted a site from IIS7 and even deleted its physical path. But the site is still accessible. Could anybody provide theory (caching?) and a solution to clear the IIS cache?

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess: maybe a copy of your files is in the Default Web Sites' (standard: `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot`)?

In that case, if IIS' Default Web Site is enabled it will accept all host headers and answer to requests of your deleted web site.

I would to try to stop the IIS and see if you still get the site. If you still get pages, the site is probably on a different server.

Answer (score 1):

I would check IIS logfiles to verify if the site is still been served from the same server. If you have deleted the site from IIS, there is no ways the site is accessable. I would also check if there is any device in between the client and server that would have cached the pages.

Comment: And make sure that you are not seeing browser cached pages or Proxy pages as well.

Comment: maybe it is something different. I deleted index.html of the first created website (was a duplicate as the mentioned above). Now I cant access the deleted domain as wanted. I don't know why every request tries to access my first created website. Need to know more theory.

Comment: The reason is Default Web Site has * for Bindings and which means all IP's, so even though you deleted the site the request would still be served by the DWS as it was able to handle the requests.

Comment: Thank you. It is something with this related. Now I have to find out why my website1 (i.e. www.xyz.com) is treated as the Default Website

Comment: As an addendum, I also had the problem mentioned in that previous comment; in my case, the answer was that the website "www.xyz.com" had no host name defined and was set up on all available IP addresses, so it was being used for requests to recently removed websites. It was easy to fix by right clicking the site, going into "Edit Bindings…," specifying an IP address and adding a host name to the http binding.